# resultset print to txt file

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I want to print my result of the query to .txt file.
How to do it? i try to print it with or without .tostring, but it's still not the result i want.

Here is my code

```
try {
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ta", "root", "root");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    String query = "select count(no) as 'jumlah',kelompok from email group by kelompok";
    //System.out.println(query);
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

    while (rs.next()) {
        dataset.setValue( Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1)), "Jumlah", rs.getString(2));
    }
    try {
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("OutFile.txt"));
        String jumlahemail = "select count(*) from email";
        ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery(jumlahemail);
        out.println("E-mail yang diterima adalah sebanyak: "+rs1.toString());
        out.println("Dengan detail: ");
        out.println(rs.toString());
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(GUI.Home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

the result of this is:

```
E-mail yang diterima adalah sebanyak: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@81c868
Dengan detail: 
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@8c241a
```

how to do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `rs1.toString()` you get the default `toString()` implementation of `Object`, which prints the class name and the onstance hash (`com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@81c868` in your case).

What you want to do is extract hte result of your query from the ResultSet, and print it.
Use `rs1.getInt(1)` to get the count your query fetches.

See reference [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt%28int%29).

EDIT (after edit in the question) :

First of all, I'll change the first query to :

```
String query = "select count(kelompok),kelompok from email group by kelompok";
```

since you are grouping by `kelompok`, so that's the column you want to count.

Second, your iteration over the result set :

```
while (rs.next()) {
    dataset.setValue( Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1)), "Jumlah", rs.getString(2));
}
```

I don't know what `dataset` is, but the count returns an Integer, so there's no point in trying to read a String and converting it to Integer. I suggest you use a Map :

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
while (rs.next()) {
    map.put (rs.getString(2), rs.getInt(1));
}
```

Note that I chose the key of the map to be the `kelompok` (whatever that means), and the value to be the count.

The second query seems redundant, since you can get the data it retrieves (the total count) from the result of the first query.

We can change the iteration of the first query result set to :

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
int total = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
    int count =  rs.getInt(1);
    total += count;
    map.put (rs.getString(2), count);
}
```

Now you got all you need to output the data to the file :

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("OutFile.txt"));
out.println("E-mail yang diterima adalah sebanyak: "+ total);
out.println("Dengan detail: ");
for (String s : map.keySet()) {
    out.println(s + " = " + map.get(s)); // you might want to change the formatting
}
out.close();
```

Comment: sorry, didn't paste the code well.. so, my rs1.getInt() will get number 1 to become `rs1.getInt(1)`, and my rs.toString will be inserted with number 2 to become `rs.toString(2)`? ps:i already edited the code, my rs is to count each category. i want to show it up at my txt file, for example: apple 3, orange 2, etc

Answer (score 0):

**What is rs.toString() ?It is not clear.**

```
try {
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("OutFile.txt"));
    String jumlahemail = "select count(*) from email";
    ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery(jumlahemail);
    out.println("E-mail yang diterima adalah sebanyak: "+rs1.getInt(1));
    out.println("Dengan detail: ");
    out.println(rs.toString());
    out.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

try  this code.

Comment: sorry, didn't paste the code well.. so, my rs1.getInt() will get number 1 to become `rs1.getInt(1)`, and my rs.toString will be inserted with number 2 to become `rs.toString(2)`?

Comment: ps:i already edited the code, my rs is to count each category. i want to show it up at my txt file, for example: apple 3, orange 2, etc

Answer (score 0):

First of all things dont work like this in java

```
        ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery(jumlahemail);
        out.println("E-mail yang diterima adalah sebanyak: "+rs1.toString());
        out.println("Dengan detail: ");
        out.println(rs.toString());
```

What you are trying to achieve with this `rs1.toString()` If you call toString() on any object it will just give you the `full-qualified-name-of-the-class@HashCode`.

If you want to get the data out of `ResultSet` you need to iterate through the `ResultSet` first using `next()` something like this

```
ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery(jumlahemail);
while(rs1.next())
{          
    out.println("E-mail yang diterima adalah sebanyak: " + rset.getInt(1));
    out.println("Dengan detail: ");
 }
```